# How does closing a socket affects other's side read

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp

For example we have a server-client application. If the server write a message on the socket and then close it before the client's read. Will the client be able to read the message?

Comment: Please specify an operating system and sockets interface.

Comment: What do sockets have to do with C++ or C?  Sockets is an interface that can be accessed, language agnostic.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews My project is on C that's why i tagged C/C++, i didn't know if the sockets works in a different way on other languages

Comment: BTW, C is a different language than C++.  For example, C++ has templates and `std::string`.  The C language has character arrays and you can have variable called "class".  There is no such language as C/C++.

Comment: My understanding is that the socket code will behave the same whether you use Java, Fortran or Visual Basic.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  C and C++  has common libraries for sockets

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"If the server write a message on the socket and then close it before the client's read. Will the client be able to read the message?"

Yes. The client will get the data that was sent before the FIN packet that closes the socket.

Comment: Assuming the server closes the socket gracefully to produce a FIN at all, that is

Comment: @RemyLebeau Of course. If the server process crashes or just `exit`s or the OS at either end has a bug or someone yanks out the network cable or enough intermediate network infrastructure evaporates. Etc. Then noone can make any sane guess as to what will happen.

Comment: What if the FIN outruns the data and reaches the client/server first. Is it guaranteed to still be able to read?

Comment: @Chipster all TCP packets have a sequence number. The network stack (usually implemented in the OS kernel) is responsible for delivering packets to the application in-order and delay delivery or request re-transmission of packets as appropriate. From the applications point of view, a TCP connection is an ordered stream of bytes and it will never see things arrive out-of-order. Things are different with UDP.

Answer (score -3):

This behavior is implementation specific, in general, you should not assume the client is able to read the message, the `close(2)` in the Linux manual says:

```
Be sure to use shutdown(2) to shut down all parts the connection before closing the socket.
```

If you want to ensure that a client has read that message, make that client acknowledge that action in your application protocol.

When you send data through the socket and then you close that same socket, there's no guarantee that the kernel has emptied it's internal buffers to the network or even could do so (eventual problematic network conditions).

Comment: "When you send data through the socket and then you close that same socket, there's no guarantee that the kernel has emptied it's internal buffers to the network" - No, you don't know that. But it *will* do that. It won't just discard outstanding data on close.

Comment: I don't think this is answering the question. The question asks about client-server, which implies 2 different processes and descriptors used for sockets -- and this answer refers to blocking _on a different thread (same process), on the same socket_

Comment: This is wrong. The connection will linger inside the kernel and ensure the buffers are emptied, even after the socket is closed. You can make your program block on `close()`, waiting for the connection to be finished by using the option using SO_LINGER.

Comment: It will discard outstanding data on close if it could not send it, and you'll get an error out of `close(2)`.

Comment: @Bitwize To clarify, I did not mean to refer to the entire block quoted text, edited my answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Closing the socket does not shutdown TCP protocol behaviors. It will retry until ACK or give up as usual.

Comment: @lvella Oh yeah :D It's not going to FIN until it's emptied the buffer and had it all ACKd I suppose

Comment: @lvella Are you sure about that? It seems to me that asking to `close(2)` means you want the system resources behind the file descriptor cleaned up. Care to share a reference to such information?

Comment: "eventual problematic network conditions" applies *always*. Nothing about `close` is special in that regard. If you send something and *never* close the socket, "eventual problematic network conditions" could still prevent the recipient from recieving the data.

Comment: I would assume it frees resources at a certain level but the underlying network driver stuff is still doing its thing and managing its own resources as it always has

Comment: Indeed, the manpage specifically says that when your FD represents a file, `close` doesn't really do any magic thing to the file. You're just closing a handle. Syncing/buffering/etc is still going on underneath.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Sure, well if that is wrong for **Linux** so be it. I prefer to not assume much on kernel behavior in that regard, or rather decide not to depend on it possibly creating portability problems.

Comment: Granted we're all assuming BSD-like `close` here. I think it's a fair assumption though particularly as every sockets impl I know almost certainly works like this.

Comment: @LeoLeBouter Yes, I am sure, but unfortunately I don't have a reference. I don't think that is explicitly specified somewhere, but you can glue the pieces together: sockets are a POSIX interface for every kind of network, including TCP/IP, Unix sockets, X25, etc. `close()` is part of this interface, and disables the socket. For it to change the expected behavior of TCP/IP would be a very weird exception for the implementation to make.